# Adding environment vars to remote development in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, remote-debugging

There are already a number of posts about using remote development in PyCharm but as far as I can tell none of them describe this specific question.

In PyCharm we can use Remote Development, for instance by using an SSH environment and running everything off a server. I am using this successfully and apart from a quirk here and there I am quite satisfied.

One issue that I am facing, however, is that I sometimes need to run GPU-accelerated code. Usually, if I were to submit/run a job I would just use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` or something similar to specify which device to run my job on. My question is, how can I tell PyCharm to *always* use this environment variable for this remote development and not having to specify it each time when trying to run a script? This way, I could ask the rest of my team to each do the same so everyone has their one dedicated GPU to work on.

I am aware that I can still use the terminal to run my scripts or use the script-specific configs in PyCharm, but those are specific to one single command. I want the environment variable to be used for *all* python call to the remote server. How can I do that?

Comment: We use "login shell" to launch an IDE remotely. AFAIK exporting the variable in ".bash_profile" file of the remote user should help. Is it helps?

Comment: @VladE. But then it is set during all my sessions. I do not want that. I only want to set it during my remote PyCharm sessions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this scenario is not implemented. Feel free to create an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue in the Getaway and Remote Development tracker